# Mousedown delegation not work with D3 drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, d3.js, mousedown

I have been writing an application using **Angular 2** and **D3.js V4**.
The main problem is that when I attach the d3 drag event and Angular **@HostListener('document:mousedown')** to the element, the second will be not invoked for **left** mouse button (but ok for **middle** and **right**). But if comment the drag event - it will be ok. I have wrote simple example using jQuery and D3. Could anybody explain, what's going on?

[JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/pifewidahe/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <g>
                <rect transform="translate(10 10)"width="50" height="50" fill="black"></rect>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).on('mousedown', 'g', function(event) {
    console.log('mousedown delegation');
})

d3.select('g')
  .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', () => {
            console.log('drag started')
        })
        .on('drag', () => {
            console.log('dragged')
        }))
```